# Send plain soap over http using camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am trying to set up a very simple route to send SOAP content over http and then show the response:

```
<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <setBody>
        <constant><![CDATA[<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP:Header></SOAP:Header><SOAP:Body></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>]]>
        </constant>
    </setBody>
    <to uri="https://localhost:8443/api"/>
    <log message="${out.body}"/>
</route>
```

I am not getting any error but is not really showing the response.

What am I missing here?

I am simply runnig my app like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ApplicationContext
                ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-config.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Without either a SOAPAction http header, WS Adressing header, or SOAP body contents there is no way your web service could do any dispatching to a service method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set some headers.

Try to modify your route like below:

```xml
 <route>
     <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=60000"/>
     <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
         <constant>POST</constant>
     </setHeader>
     <setHeader headerName="Content-type">
         <constant>text/xml;charset=UTF-8</constant>
     </setHeader>
     <setHeader headerName="Accept-Encoding">
         <constant>gzip,deflate</constant>
     </setHeader>

     <setBody>
         <constant><![CDATA[<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP:Header></SOAP:Header><SOAP:Body></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>]]>
      </constant>
      </setBody>
      <to uri="https://localhost:8443/api"/>
      <log message="${out.body}"/>
  </route>
```

I have changed the beginning of the route, because I don't know how you're sending messages to `direct:start`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was misusing the direct: component, from the documentation it looks like I can call it from another route. I also took a Main class I found in some of the camel jars to have the application running.

Comment: Yes, you're right about `direct` component, you can call the route, beginning from `direct` (`<from uri="direct:start"/>`) from another route (`<to uri="direct:start"/>`).